# How to access different models in record rules in Odoo V10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to access `op.faculty` model in `op.student` for which I am creating record rule.

[('x_school_id', '=', user.x_school_id)]

The purpose of `faculty` model - They(Faculty user) can see only assigned students.
Through record rule, we want to match faculty and student models together.

Comment: What is the purpose of faculty on the student model? What is the record rule trying to achieve? Can you include the model/field definitions from each model?

Comment: The purpose of faculty model - They(Faculty user) can see only assigned students. Through record rule, we want to match faculty and student models together.

Comment: Can you include your `op.faculty` and `op.student` models (with their relevant fields) in your question? I understand now what you're wanting but I want to make sure I answer appropriately based on what you have.

Comment: In `op.faculty` fields are :-  x_school_id, x_class_id.
In `op.student` fields are :- x_class_id.
I want to bind both the models with the help of `res.users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can "access another model" from the current model you're working with on the record rule is through a `fields` attributes.

Add a relational field to the `op.student` model to pull any data that you need for `op.faculty`. I'm not sure your exact scenario but you should be able to link together models however you need such as the following:

```py
from odoo import fields, models

class Faculty(models.Model):
    _name = 'op.faculty'

    school_id = fields.Many2one('op.school')
    school_student_ids = fields.One2many(related='school_id.student_ids')
    my_student_ids = fields.One2many('op.student', 'mentor_id')

class Student(models.Model):
    _name = 'op.student'

    school_id = fields.Many2one('op.school')
    school_faculty = fields.One2many(related='school_id.faculty_ids')
    mentor_id = fields.Many2one('op.faculty')

class School(models.Model):
    _name = 'op.school'

    faculty_ids = fields.One2many('op.faculty', 'school_id')
    student_ids = fields.One2many('op.student', 'school_id')
```